# Local SEO Strategies

Tags: seo, best-practices, local-seo

What are your strategies for local SEO? For example, if you had a web design company in Lincoln, Nebraska, what would you do for your website from an SEO perspective?

Comment: If this question were asked today I would close it as being too broad.  Local SEO is too big of a topic to cover in a couple paragraphs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After claiming your listing with Google Places as well as Bing, and BOTW local listings. I start with the local citation finder. This shows where your top local competitors are promoting their website http://www.whitespark.ca/tools/local-citation-finder/ and will give you a good idea of where to promote locally.

Also depending on the industry Yelp can be a great resource.

Comment: Being on the google map is big big big for local visitors.

Answer (score 10):

Be sure you use the `<address>` HTML tag and place your address in it. If you don't want to use your home address use a PO Box or a UPS store address (be sure to have a box there). Place it in the footer of your website and on your contact page.

Also, add your business to [Google Places](http://www.google.com/local/add/businessCenter).

Comment: address tag cool +1.

Comment: Can the <address> tag be combined with microformat tags, or does it conflict/add duplication?

Answer (score 5):

Along with John Conde directions, also try including rich snippets markup, to add more semantic juice. Check http://microformats.org/

Comment: +1 for microdata. I think this is a real secret and could help small businesses push ahead of their competition quickly.