# What Does Local SEO Consist of and How Does it Differ From Website SEO?

Tags: seo, search-engines, optimization, local-seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Local SEO Strategies](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5531/local-seo-strategies)

What does most local SEO services consist of? So far here's what I got:

- Add company to Google Places, Yahoo Local, Bing Local and a bunch of
  other local engines like Yelp and yellowpages etc.
- Submit website to the 3 search engines up and get verified.
- Edit your WHOIS to have your address and keep address consistency
  throughout all pages, branding, engines.
- Get a Linkedin account for the business

I feel like i'm being pretty naive though since most other companies are charging monthly fees. I look at most of these are one time set ups: fill out profile with pictures, keywords and some good reviews. Are there some key points I am missing?

I've also seen companies talk about keyword research, but isn't that a website seo issue vs local seo issue? I feel local seo is supposed to go to these directory outlets before your website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While those steps are the most common there is more that can be done depending on the client and what they want out of a local SEO campaign. I've negotiated with local websites lower ad rates for my clients, managed their Groupon campaigns, AdWords campaigns etc.

Local businesses need local exposure, so running ad campaigns on local sites, facebook ads targeted to locals. Geo targeted PPC campaigns. Videos are great, and geo-tagging everything is a plus.

The main difference I believe is that local SEO is for companies who have a web presence and use it to get foot traffic or clients for their local businesses like contractors. Rather than relying on their website to generate revenue which is global for an online business.

Comment: So when it comes to companies charging monthly for updates - it's mostly for things like adword campaigns?

Comment: Depends on their packages, I haven't seen many which include managing PPC campaigns. I always suggest it and it's just a few bucks a month to manage a local SEO campaign, plus you can get a few hundred in free ad credits for new advertisers so it's a no brainer to use. The recurring work in packages is typically more reviews, and maybe managing the social media accounts like tweeting or adding photos and videos each month provided by the client. I'm sure it varies from company to company. I personally discuss the clients needs and create custom packages.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to determine the differences in what search engines see as important between "normal" SEO and Local SEO can be found by comparing the following articles:

- [SEO Ranking Factors from SEOMoz](http://www.seomoz.org/article/search-ranking-factors)
- [Local Ranking Factors from David Mihm](http://www.davidmihm.com/local-search-ranking-factors.shtml)